# No more spool space for query in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, alation

I am using Teradata database but I am quite new to its functioning. Could you please help me with making the below query more efficient so that it does not yield 'no more spool space' error? It is getting too heavy after I add the 2nd join.

```
SELECT
  a.src_cmpgn_code,
  a.cmc_name,
  SUM(b.open_cnt)
FROM access_views.dw_cmc_lkp a
LEFT JOIN prs_restricted_v.mh_crm_engmnt_sd b
  ON b.cmpgn_id = a.cmc_id
LEFT JOIN access_views.dw_cmc_instnc c
  ON b.cmpgn_id = c.cmc_id
WHERE 1=1
  AND b.trigger_dt BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
  AND b.site_cntry_id = 1
  AND a.cmpgn_group_name IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
  AND c.dlvry_vhcl_id IN (1, 10)
  AND c.chnl_id = 1
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Explain looks like this:

> This query is optimized using type 2 profile Cost_NoSlidingJ_Profile,
>   profileid 10007. 1) First, we lock mdm_tables.DW_CMC_INSTNC in view
>   access_views.dw_cmc_instnc for access, we lock MDM_TABLES.DW_CMC_LKP
>   in view access_views.dw_cmc_lkp for access, and we lock
>   PRS_T.MH_CRM_ENGMNT_SD in view prs_restricted_v.mh_crm_engmnt_sd for
>   access. 2) Next, we do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from 365 partitions
>   of PRS_T.MH_CRM_ENGMNT_SD in view prs_restricted_v.mh_crm_engmnt_sd
>   with a condition of ("(NOT (PRS_T.MH_CRM_ENGMNT_SD in view
>   prs_restricted_v.mh_crm_engmnt_sd.CMPGN_ID IS NULL )) AND
>   (((PRS_T.MH_CRM_ENGMNT_SD in view
>   prs_restricted_v.mh_crm_engmnt_sd.TRIGGER_DT <= DATE '2019-12-31') AND
>   (PRS_T.MH_CRM_ENGMNT_SD.TRIGGER_DT >= DATE '2019-01-01')) AND
>   (PRS_T.MH_CRM_ENGMNT_SD in view
>   prs_restricted_v.mh_crm_engmnt_sd.SITE_CNTRY_ID = 1. ))") into Spool 4
>   (all_amps), which is redistributed by the hash code of (
>   PRS_T.MH_CRM_ENGMNT_SD.CMPGN_ID) to all AMPs. The size of Spool 4 is
>   estimated with no confidence to be 329,656,959 rows ( 7,582,110,057
>   bytes). The estimated time for this step is 2.40 seconds. 3) We do an
>   all-AMPs JOIN step from MDM_TABLES.DW_CMC_LKP in view
>   access_views.dw_cmc_lkp by way of an all-rows scan with a condition of
>   ("MDM_TABLES.DW_CMC_LKP in view
>   access_views.dw_cmc_lkp.CMPGN_GROUP_NAME IN ('Bucks_Nectar_eBayPlus',
>   'DailyDeal','Other','STEP_User_Agreement')"), which is joined to Spool
>   4 (Last Use) by way of an all-rows scan. MDM_TABLES.DW_CMC_LKP and
>   Spool 4 are joined using a single partition hash join, with a join
>   condition of ("CMPGN_ID = MDM_TABLES.DW_CMC_LKP.CMC_ID"). The result
>   goes into Spool 5 (all_amps) fanned out into 5 hash join partitions,
>   which is built locally on the AMPs. The size of Spool 5 is estimated
>   with no confidence to be 79,119,821 rows (10,681,175,835 bytes). The
>   estimated time for this step is 0.19 seconds. 4) We do an all-AMPs
>   RETRIEVE step from mdm_tables.DW_CMC_INSTNC in view
>   access_views.dw_cmc_instnc by way of an all-rows scan with a condition
>   of ("(mdm_tables.DW_CMC_INSTNC in view
>   access_views.dw_cmc_instnc.DLVRY_VHCL_ID IN (1 , 10 )) AND
>   ((mdm_tables.DW_CMC_INSTNC in view access_views.dw_cmc_instnc.CHNL_ID
>   = 1) AND (mdm_tables.DW_CMC_INSTNC in view access_views.dw_cmc_instnc.TRTMNT_TYPE_CODE <> 'I'))") into Spool 6
>   (all_amps) fanned out into 5 hash join partitions, which is
>   redistributed by the hash code of ( mdm_tables.DW_CMC_INSTNC.CMC_ID)
>   to all AMPs. The size of Spool 6 is estimated with no confidence to be
>   2,874,675 rows (48,869,475 bytes). The estimated time for this step is
>   0.58 seconds. 5) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 5 (Last Use) by way of an all-rows scan, which is joined to Spool 6 (Last Use) by
>   way of an all-rows scan. Spool 5 and Spool 6 are joined using a hash
>   join of 5 partitions, with a join condition of ("(CMPGN_ID = CMC_ID)
>   AND (CMC_ID = CMC_ID)"). The result goes into Spool 3 (all_amps),
>   which is built locally on the AMPs. The size of Spool 3 is estimated
>   with no confidence to be 5,353,507,625 rows ( 690,602,483,625 bytes).
>   The estimated time for this step is 14.82 seconds. 6) We do an
>   all-AMPs SUM step to aggregate from Spool 3 (Last Use) by way of an
>   all-rows scan , grouping by field1 (
>   MDM_TABLES.DW_CMC_LKP.SRC_CMPGN_CODE ,MDM_TABLES.DW_CMC_LKP.CMC_NAME).
>   Aggregate Intermediate Results are computed globally, then placed in
>   Spool 7. The size of Spool 7 is estimated with no confidence to be
>   11,774 rows (5,286,526 bytes). The estimated time for this step is
>   24.51 seconds. 7) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from Spool 7 (Last Use) by way of an all-rows scan into Spool 1 (group_amps), which is
>   built locally on the AMPs. The size of Spool 1 is estimated with no
>   confidence to be 11,774 rows (2,837,534 bytes). The estimated time for
>   this step is 0.01 seconds. 8) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION
>   step to all AMPs involved in processing the request. -> The contents
>   of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of statement 1. The
>   total estimated time is 42.50 seconds.

Comment: The table b and c conditions in the WHERE clause make the LEFT JOIN's return regular INNER JOIN result. Move them to ON, if you want true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: Why _LEFT JOIN_ c, when you don't use any of its columns?

Comment: What are the relations between those tables, which columns are unique, cmpgn_id, cmc_id? Are those views based on joins or a single table? Can you show Explain?

Comment: @dnoeth Added explain

Comment: Optimizer changed Outer to Inner Joins (as expected). Seems there are no usable statistics (all steps show "no confidence"). Based on the estimated 5,353,507,625 rows the join to dw_cmc_instnc is many-many instead of 1-many. Are you sure this will return the correct result?

Comment: @dnoeth The row count is definitely nonsense. The first two tables joined yield a result at about 500 rows and I expected less after joining dw_cmc_instnc and introducing conditions based on it in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @jarlh changed the joins, thank you

Comment: Can you collect stats? With better estimates join planning might change.

Comment: @dnoeth I finally got through using volatile tables and inner joining them to avoid multiplication. Thanks for the ideas.